# Can I use server-side javascript libraries with Phoenix/elixir?

Tags: elixir, graph-theory, phoenix-framework, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'd like to start using Phoenix for a personal project, with Cytoscape server-side (Cytoscape is a graph-theory library available js)
Can I use js libraries with Phoenix on the server and does it even make sense technically?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic because of asking to find an off site resource.

Comment: @JustinWood, I might have missed something, but I didn't see in the help/on-topic why I could not ask this question? If I can't ask this here, where can I? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. There is a numerical list there and it says that questions asking to find a software library, or any other off site resource is considered off-topic. This is because they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. I'll reformulate the question.

Comment: You shouldn't do this unless you absolutely have to, but you can do [something like this](https://github.com/sheharyarn/explay/blob/master/lib/explay/protobuf.ex#L28-L39) to communicate with a `node` instance that requires `cryptoscape`, does some work and sends data back.